# Using tween to turn systematically lights on and off

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs, tween

I have 5 light bulbs that I want to turn on and off by using a tween.

The light bulbs are positioned in a row and I want that in the first 3 seconds the light bulbs go on and off one after another till the fith one and then go back to the first one.

After this the tween should become slower andit should stop at a random bulb turning this one on.

How can I make this. Here is what I have done so far:

```
 function start_lights(start_lights, bulbs, iterator, speed) {
 var myimage = bulbs[iterator];
 if (iterator < bulbs.length - 1) {
     iterator++;
     speed += 10;
 }
 if(iterator == out_pilles.length-1) {

      iterator = 0;
      out_pilles.reverse();
 }
 createjs.Tween.get(myimage)
   .wait(0)
   .to({
       alpha: 0
   }, speed)
   .to({
       alpha: 1
   }, speed)
   .call(start_lights, [start_lights, bulbs, iterator, speed]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would work using events to trigger when a light transition is just finished (i.e. light1-stop, light2-stop, etc). When light1-stop is triggered you can manage the light2 tween and so on. When the light2 tween is finished you can trigger the light2-stop event and start the light3 animation, and so on.

In this way you can even work with an array of lights and then manage them dynamically.

To start automatically the animation you can trigger the light(n)-stop event by hand.

Ref: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/EventDispatcher.html